# package:// Usage

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I vaguely recall being able to use package:// to access files in packages, but I can't find the documentation and it turns out to be the kind of thing that is impossible to search for.

Can you actually access files in this manner? Is there a Wiki page about how to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9823/package://-usage/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2011-04-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you're looking for [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/resource_retriever) wiki page.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2011-05-12**:
That's what I was looking for! But alas, it's only for C++, so I made a Python version. https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4951

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not a general answer, but [camera_info_manager](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_info_manager) supports that syntax for accessing camera calibration files. I suppose other packages do, too.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-04-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1